# Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::1c)

Tags: ubuntu, apt

После подключения одного *PPA* не могу произвести
`apt-get update` без ошибок:

```
Err:6 http://archive.canonical.com focal InRelease                                                                               
Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::1c). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1b). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.191), connection timed out
Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.91.15), connection timed out
Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.92.150), connection timed out
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Взято
[оттуда](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100887/105635).)

Похоже на какие-то проблемы с *IPv6*.  Можно отключить его
использование опцией:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get update -o 'Acquire::ForceIPv4=true'
```

Если помогло, можно закрепить эту опцию таким образом:

```sh
$ sudo touch '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4'
$ echo 'Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";' | sudo tee '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4'
Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";
$
```